# ASP.NET MVC Client Side validation result in Jquery object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I m using MVC2.0, DataAnnotation for Client side Validation.

my problem is how to get Client Side Validation result like whether form validation returns TRUE or FALSE on Click of Submit button in MVC2.0.

My scenario is like, I want to open a popup window in new Tab on click of Submit button using JQuery. But if Validation is false then it should not open the popup window.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution of my problem.

```
        function doPost(form) {
            var myForm = $("#form0");
            var formContext = myForm[0]['__MVC_FormValidation'];
            var errors;
            if (formContext) {
                errors = formContext.validate("submit");
            }
            if (!formContext || errors.length == 0) {
                //PUT UR CUSTOME JS CODE HERE
            }            
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Im using the builtin javascript validation library jquery.validate.js with my models and to check whether a form is valid based on the Model rules I do the following to validate on the client:

```
var FormID = $("#FormID");
$(FormID).submit(function(e) {
    if (FormID.valid()) {
        alert("Form is valid");
    }
    else {
        alert("Form is invalid");
    }
});
```